# Multiple validation on textbox in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a ASP.Net gridview and in itemTemplete I have textbox for input purpose. The problem is some textbox is for numeric input and other for Character and some accept Mobile no and 1 row is for IP address.
Now i want to validate rows as per Row in gridview? 
is it possible if possible then how ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: http://img42.com/gTzIo

Comment: du you find solution?

Comment: i send answer did you check?

Comment: I put that work on hold. i'm doing rest of the work than at last i will come to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

here im giving an example.Not an exact answer.So try to understand the logic.Here im giving how to validate phno and only alphabets in name.remaining you can get, like the same way.
Because of dynamic generation of textboxes we cant create validations on it.So i use "*javascript*"

First you need to click "View Page source"(Right click on browser page).In that we can see the "Id"s of dynamically generated textboxes.here i take two textboxes for phno and name in gridview.i get their ids by seeing their html.(Right click on browser->view page source).i get their ids like "GridView1_TextBox1_0" for name"GridView1_TextBox1_1" for phone.By using ids i create validation using Javascript.Write the below code in Head Section of Page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var phno = document.getElementById("GridView1_TextBox1_1").value;
        var namechar = document.getElementById("GridView1_TextBox1_0").value;
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    var name = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (!namechar.match(name)) {
        alert("please enter alphabets only");
        return false;
    }

  if(!phno.match(phoneno))
        {
            alert("please enter valid phno");
            return false;  
        }  



    }
</script>
```

In this way  i validate textboxes which are generated dynamically.once again its not exact answer.its a logic by using javascript.

**Limitation:**
Hence Javascript is client side technology.if user disable the javascript.it not works.